# Django template dictsort not ordering correctly when spanish language

Tags: django

Currently I have a countrie's dict

```
COUNTRIES =  {
  "countries": [
    {
      "name_en": "Afghanistan",
      "name_es": "Afganistán",
      "dial_code": "+93",
      "code": "AF"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Albania",
      "name_es": "Albania",
      "dial_code": "+355",
      "code": "AL"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Algeria",
      "name_es": "Argelia",
      "dial_code": "+213",
      "code": "DZ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "AmericanSamoa",
      "name_es": "Samoa Americana",
      "dial_code": "+1684",
      "code": "AS"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Andorra",
      "name_es": "Andorra",
      "dial_code": "+376",
      "code": "AD"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Angola",
      "name_es": "Angola",
      "dial_code": "+244",
      "code": "AO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Anguilla",
      "name_es": "Anguilla",
      "dial_code": "+1264",
      "code": "AI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Antarctica",
      "name_es": "Antártida",
      "dial_code": "+672",
      "code": "AQ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Antigua and Barbuda",
      "name_es": "Antigua y Barbuda",
      "dial_code": "+1268",
      "code": "AG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Argentina",
      "name_es": "Argentina",
      "dial_code": "+54",
      "code": "AR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Armenia",
      "name_es": "Armenia",
      "dial_code": "+374",
      "code": "AM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Aruba",
      "name_es": "Aruba",
      "dial_code": "+297",
      "code": "AW"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Australia",
      "name_es": "Australia",
      "dial_code": "+61",
      "code": "AU"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Austria",
      "name_es": "Austria",
      "dial_code": "+43",
      "code": "AT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Azerbaijan",
      "name_es": "Azerbaiyán",
      "dial_code": "+994",
      "code": "AZ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Bahamas",
      "name_es": "Bahamas",
      "dial_code": "+1242",
      "code": "BS"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Bahrain",
      "name_es": "Baréin",
      "dial_code": "+973",
      "code": "BH"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Bangladesh",
      "name_es": "Banglades",
      "dial_code": "+880",
      "code": "BD"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Barbados",
      "name_es": "Barbados",
      "dial_code": "+1246",
      "code": "BB"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Belarus",
      "name_es": "Bielorrusia",
      "dial_code": "+375",
      "code": "BY"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Belgium",
      "name_es": "Bélgica",
      "dial_code": "+32",
      "code": "BE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Belize",
      "name_es": "Belice",
      "dial_code": "+501",
      "code": "BZ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Benin",
      "name_es": "Benin",
      "dial_code": "+229",
      "code": "BJ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Bermuda",
      "name_es": "Bermudas",
      "dial_code": "+1441",
      "code": "BM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Bhutan",
      "name_es": "Butan",
      "dial_code": "+975",
      "code": "BT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Bolivia",
      "name_es": "Bolivia",
      "dial_code": "+591",
      "code": "BO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
      "name_es": "Bosnia-Herzegovina",
      "dial_code": "+387",
      "code": "BA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Botswana",
      "name_es": "Botsuana",
      "dial_code": "+267",
      "code": "BW"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Brazil",
      "name_es": "Brasil",
      "dial_code": "+55",
      "code": "BR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "British Indian Ocean Territory",
      "name_es": "Territorio Británico del Océano Índico",
      "dial_code": "+246",
      "code": "IO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Brunei Darussalam",
      "name_es": "Brunei",
      "dial_code": "+673",
      "code": "BN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Bulgaria",
      "name_es": "Bulgaria",
      "dial_code": "+359",
      "code": "BG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Burkina Faso",
      "name_es": "Burkina Faso",
      "dial_code": "+226",
      "code": "BF"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Burundi",
      "name_es": "Burundi",
      "dial_code": "+257",
      "code": "BI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Cambodia",
      "name_es": "Camboya",
      "dial_code": "+855",
      "code": "KH"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Cameroon",
      "name_es": "Camerún",
      "dial_code": "+237",
      "code": "CM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Canada",
      "name_es": "Canadá",
      "dial_code": "+1",
      "code": "CA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Cape Verde",
      "name_es": "Cabo Verde",
      "dial_code": "+238",
      "code": "CV"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Cayman Islands",
      "name_es": "Islas Caimán",
      "dial_code": "+ 345",
      "code": "KY"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Central African Republic",
      "name_es": "República Centroafricana",
      "dial_code": "+236",
      "code": "CF"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Chad",
      "name_es": "Chad",
      "dial_code": "+235",
      "code": "TD"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Chile",
      "name_es": "Chile",
      "dial_code": "+56",
      "code": "CL"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "China",
      "name_es": "China",
      "dial_code": "+86",
      "code": "CN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Christmas Island",
      "name_es": "Isla de Navidad",
      "dial_code": "+61",
      "code": "CX"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
      "name_es": "Islas Cocos",
      "dial_code": "+61",
      "code": "CC"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Colombia",
      "name_es": "Colombia",
      "dial_code": "+57",
      "code": "CO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Comoros",
      "name_es": "Comoras",
      "dial_code": "+269",
      "code": "KM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Congo",
      "name_es": "Congo",
      "dial_code": "+242",
      "code": "CG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the",
      "name_es": "República Democrática del Congo",
      "dial_code": "+243",
      "code": "CD"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Cook Islands",
      "name_es": "Islas Cook",
      "dial_code": "+682",
      "code": "CK"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Costa Rica",
      "name_es": "Costa Rica",
      "dial_code": "+506",
      "code": "CR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Cote d'Ivoire",
      "name_es": "Costa de Marfil",
      "dial_code": "+225",
      "code": "CI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Croatia",
      "name_es": "Croacia",
      "dial_code": "+385",
      "code": "HR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Cuba",
      "name_es": "Cuba",
      "dial_code": "+53",
      "code": "CU"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Cyprus",
      "name_es": "Chipre",
      "dial_code": "+537",
      "code": "CY"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Czechia",
      "name_es": "Chequia",
      "dial_code": "+420",
      "code": "CZ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Denmark",
      "name_es": "Dinamarca",
      "dial_code": "+45",
      "code": "DK"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Djibouti",
      "name_es": "Yibuti",
      "dial_code": "+253",
      "code": "DJ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Dominica",
      "name_es": "Dominica",
      "dial_code": "+1767",
      "code": "DM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Dominican Republic",
      "name_es": "República Dominicana",
      "dial_code": "+1849",
      "code": "DO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Ecuador",
      "name_es": "Ecuador",
      "dial_code": "+593",
      "code": "EC"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Egypt",
      "name_es": "Egipto",
      "dial_code": "+20",
      "code": "EG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "El Salvador",
      "name_es": "El Salvador",
      "dial_code": "+503",
      "code": "SV"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Equatorial Guinea",
      "name_es": "Guinea Ecuatorial",
      "dial_code": "+240",
      "code": "GQ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Eritrea",
      "name_es": "Eritrea",
      "dial_code": "+291",
      "code": "ER"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Estonia",
      "name_es": "Estonia",
      "dial_code": "+372",
      "code": "EE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Ethiopia",
      "name_es": "Etiopía",
      "dial_code": "+251",
      "code": "ET"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",
      "name_es": "Islas Malvinas",
      "dial_code": "+500",
      "code": "FK"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Faroe Islands",
      "name_es": "Islas Feroe",
      "dial_code": "+298",
      "code": "FO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Fiji",
      "name_es": "Fiyi",
      "dial_code": "+679",
      "code": "FJ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Finland",
      "name_es": "Finlandia",
      "dial_code": "+358",
      "code": "FI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "France",
      "name_es": "Francia",
      "dial_code": "+33",
      "code": "FR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "French Guiana",
      "name_es": "Guayana Francesa",
      "dial_code": "+594",
      "code": "GF"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "French Polynesia",
      "name_es": "Polinesia Francesa",
      "dial_code": "+689",
      "code": "PF"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Gabon",
      "name_es": "Gabón",
      "dial_code": "+241",
      "code": "GA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Gambia",
      "name_es": "Gambia",
      "dial_code": "+220",
      "code": "GM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Georgia",
      "name_es": "Georgia",
      "dial_code": "+995",
      "code": "GE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Germany",
      "name_es": "Alemania",
      "dial_code": "+49",
      "code": "DE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Ghana",
      "name_es": "Ghana",
      "dial_code": "+233",
      "code": "GH"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Gibraltar",
      "name_es": "Gibraltar",
      "dial_code": "+350",
      "code": "GI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Greece",
      "name_es": "Grecia",
      "dial_code": "+30",
      "code": "GR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Greenland",
      "name_es": "Groenlandia",
      "dial_code": "+299",
      "code": "GL"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Grenada",
      "name_es": "Granada",
      "dial_code": "+1473",
      "code": "GD"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Guadeloupe",
      "name_es": "Guadalupe",
      "dial_code": "+590",
      "code": "GP"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Guam",
      "name_es": "Guam",
      "dial_code": "+1671",
      "code": "GU"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Guatemala",
      "name_es": "Guatemala",
      "dial_code": "+502",
      "code": "GT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Guernsey",
      "name_es": "Guernsey",
      "dial_code": "+44",
      "code": "GG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Guinea",
      "name_es": "Guinea",
      "dial_code": "+224",
      "code": "GN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Guinea-Bissau",
      "name_es": "Guinea-Bisau",
      "dial_code": "+245",
      "code": "GW"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Guyana",
      "name_es": "Guyana",
      "dial_code": "+595",
      "code": "GY"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Haiti",
      "name_es": "Haití",
      "dial_code": "+509",
      "code": "HT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
      "name_es": "Ciudad del Vaticano",
      "dial_code": "+379",
      "code": "VA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Honduras",
      "name_es": "Honduras",
      "dial_code": "+504",
      "code": "HN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Hong Kong",
      "name_es": "Hong Kong",
      "dial_code": "+852",
      "code": "HK"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Hungary",
      "name_es": "Hungría",
      "dial_code": "+36",
      "code": "HU"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Iceland",
      "name_es": "Islandia",
      "dial_code": "+354",
      "code": "IS"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "India",
      "name_es": "India",
      "dial_code": "+91",
      "code": "IN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Indonesia",
      "name_es": "Indonesia",
      "dial_code": "+62",
      "code": "ID"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Iran, Islamic Republic of",
      "name_es": "Irán",
      "dial_code": "+98",
      "code": "IR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Iraq",
      "name_es": "Iraq",
      "dial_code": "+964",
      "code": "IQ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Ireland",
      "name_es": "Irlanda",
      "dial_code": "+353",
      "code": "IE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Isle of Man",
      "name_es": "Isla de Man",
      "dial_code": "+44",
      "code": "IM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Israel",
      "name_es": "Israel",
      "dial_code": "+972",
      "code": "IL"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Italy",
      "name_es": "Italia",
      "dial_code": "+39",
      "code": "IT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Jamaica",
      "name_es": "Jamaica",
      "dial_code": "+1876",
      "code": "JM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Japan",
      "name_es": "Japón",
      "dial_code": "+81",
      "code": "JP"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Jersey",
      "name_es": "Jersey",
      "dial_code": "+44",
      "code": "JE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Jordan",
      "name_es": "Jordania",
      "dial_code": "+962",
      "code": "JO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Kazakhstan",
      "name_es": "Kazajistán",
      "dial_code": "+7",
      "code": "KZ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Kenya",
      "name_es": "Kenia",
      "dial_code": "+254",
      "code": "KE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Kiribati",
      "name_es": "Kiribati",
      "dial_code": "+686",
      "code": "KI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",
      "name_es": "Corea del Norte",
      "dial_code": "+850",
      "code": "KP"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Korea, Republic of",
      "name_es": "Corea del Sur",
      "dial_code": "+82",
      "code": "KR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Kosovo",
      "name_es": "Kosovo",
      "dial_code": "+383",
      "code": "XK"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Kuwait",
      "name_es": "Kuwait",
      "dial_code": "+965",
      "code": "KW"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Kyrgyzstan",
      "name_es": "Kirguistán",
      "dial_code": "+996",
      "code": "KG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Lao People's Democratic Republic",
      "name_es": "Laos",
      "dial_code": "+856",
      "code": "LA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Latvia",
      "name_es": "Letonia",
      "dial_code": "+371",
      "code": "LV"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Lebanon",
      "name_es": "Líbano",
      "dial_code": "+961",
      "code": "LB"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Lesotho",
      "name_es": "Lesoto",
      "dial_code": "+266",
      "code": "LS"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Liberia",
      "name_es": "Liberia",
      "dial_code": "+231",
      "code": "LR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya",
      "name_es": "Libia",
      "dial_code": "+218",
      "code": "LY"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Liechtenstein",
      "name_es": "Liechtenstein",
      "dial_code": "+423",
      "code": "LI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Lithuania",
      "name_es": "Lituania",
      "dial_code": "+370",
      "code": "LT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Luxembourg",
      "name_es": "Luxemburgo",
      "dial_code": "+352",
      "code": "LU"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Macao",
      "name_es": "Macao",
      "dial_code": "+853",
      "code": "MO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of",
      "name_es": "República de Macedonia",
      "dial_code": "+389",
      "code": "MK"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Madagascar",
      "name_es": "Madagascar",
      "dial_code": "+261",
      "code": "MG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Malawi",
      "name_es": "Malaui",
      "dial_code": "+265",
      "code": "MW"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Malaysia",
      "name_es": "Malasia",
      "dial_code": "+60",
      "code": "MY"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Maldives",
      "name_es": "Maldivas",
      "dial_code": "+960",
      "code": "MV"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Mali",
      "name_es": "Malí",
      "dial_code": "+223",
      "code": "ML"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Malta",
      "name_es": "Malta",
      "dial_code": "+356",
      "code": "MT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Marshall Islands",
      "name_es": "Islas Marshall",
      "dial_code": "+692",
      "code": "MH"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Martinique",
      "name_es": "Martinica",
      "dial_code": "+596",
      "code": "MQ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Mauritania",
      "name_es": "Mauritania",
      "dial_code": "+222",
      "code": "MR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Mauritius",
      "name_es": "Mauricio",
      "dial_code": "+230",
      "code": "MU"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Mayotte",
      "name_es": "Mayotte",
      "dial_code": "+262",
      "code": "YT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Mexico",
      "name_es": "México",
      "dial_code": "+52",
      "code": "MX"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Micronesia, Federated States of",
      "name_es": "Estados Federados de Micronesia",
      "dial_code": "+691",
      "code": "FM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Moldova, Republic of",
      "name_es": "Moldavia",
      "dial_code": "+373",
      "code": "MD"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Monaco",
      "name_es": "Monaco",
      "dial_code": "+377",
      "code": "MC"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Mongolia",
      "name_es": "Mongolia",
      "dial_code": "+976",
      "code": "MN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Montenegro",
      "name_es": "Montenegro",
      "dial_code": "+382",
      "code": "ME"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Montserrat",
      "name_es": "Montserrat",
      "dial_code": "+1664",
      "code": "MS"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Morocco",
      "name_es": "Marruecos",
      "dial_code": "+212",
      "code": "MA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Mozambique",
      "name_es": "Mozambique",
      "dial_code": "+258",
      "code": "MZ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Myanmar",
      "name_es": "Birmania",
      "dial_code": "+95",
      "code": "MM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Namibia",
      "name_es": "Namibia",
      "dial_code": "+264",
      "code": "NA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Nauru",
      "name_es": "Nauru",
      "dial_code": "+674",
      "code": "NR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Nepal",
      "name_es": "Nepal",
      "dial_code": "+977",
      "code": "NP"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Netherlands",
      "name_es": "Holanda",
      "dial_code": "+31",
      "code": "NL"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Netherlands Antilles",
      "name_es": "Antillas Holandesas",
      "dial_code": "+599",
      "code": "AN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "New Caledonia",
      "name_es": "Nueva Caledonia",
      "dial_code": "+687",
      "code": "NC"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "New Zealand",
      "name_es": "Nueva Zelanda",
      "dial_code": "+64",
      "code": "NZ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Nicaragua",
      "name_es": "Nicaragua",
      "dial_code": "+505",
      "code": "NI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Niger",
      "name_es": "Niger",
      "dial_code": "+227",
      "code": "NE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Nigeria",
      "name_es": "Nigeria",
      "dial_code": "+234",
      "code": "NG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Niue",
      "name_es": "Niue",
      "dial_code": "+683",
      "code": "NU"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "NorfolkIsland",
      "name_es": "IslaNorfolk",
      "dial_code": "+672",
      "code": "NF"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "NorthernMarianaIslands",
      "name_es": "IslasMarianasdelNorte",
      "dial_code": "+1670",
      "code": "MP"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Norway",
      "name_es": "Noruega",
      "dial_code": "+47",
      "code": "NO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Oman",
      "name_es": "Omán",
      "dial_code": "+968",
      "code": "OM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Pakistan",
      "name_es": "Pakistán",
      "dial_code": "+92",
      "code": "PK"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Palau",
      "name_es": "Palaos",
      "dial_code": "+680",
      "code": "PW"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Panama",
      "name_es": "Panamá",
      "dial_code": "+507",
      "code": "PA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Papua New Guinea",
      "name_es": "Papúa Nueva Guinea",
      "dial_code": "+675",
      "code": "PG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Paraguay",
      "name_es": "Paraguay",
      "dial_code": "+595",
      "code": "PY"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Peru",
      "name_es": "Perú",
      "dial_code": "+51",
      "code": "PE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Philippines",
      "name_es": "Filipinas",
      "dial_code": "+63",
      "code": "PH"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Pitcairn",
      "name_es": "Islas Pitcairn",
      "dial_code": "+872",
      "code": "PN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Poland",
      "name_es": "Polonia",
      "dial_code": "+48",
      "code": "PL"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Portugal",
      "name_es": "Portugal",
      "dial_code": "+351",
      "code": "PT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Puerto Rico",
      "name_es": "Puerto Rico",
      "dial_code": "+1939",
      "code": "PR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Qatar",
      "name_es": "Qatar",
      "dial_code": "+974",
      "code": "QA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Romania",
      "name_es": "Rumania",
      "dial_code": "+40",
      "code": "RO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Russia",
      "name_es": "Rusia",
      "dial_code": "+7",
      "code": "RU"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Rwanda",
      "name_es": "Ruanda",
      "dial_code": "+250",
      "code": "RW"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Réunion",
      "name_es": "Reunion",
      "dial_code": "+262",
      "code": "RE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Saint Barthélemy",
      "name_es": "San Bartolome",
      "dial_code": "+590",
      "code": "BL"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan Da Cunha",
      "name_es": "Santa Elena, Ascensión y Tristán de Acuña",
      "dial_code": "+290",
      "code": "SH"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
      "name_es": "San Cristóbal y Nieves",
      "dial_code": "+1869",
      "code": "KN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Saint Lucia",
      "name_es": "Santa Lucía",
      "dial_code": "+1758",
      "code": "LC"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Saint Martin",
      "name_es": "Isla de San Martín",
      "dial_code": "+590",
      "code": "MF"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
      "name_es": "San Pedro y Miquelon",
      "dial_code": "+508",
      "code": "PM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
      "name_es": "San Vicente y las Granadinas",
      "dial_code": "+1784",
      "code": "VC"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Samoa",
      "name_es": "Samoa",
      "dial_code": "+685",
      "code": "WS"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "San Marino",
      "name_es": "San Marino",
      "dial_code": "+378",
      "code": "SM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Sao Tome and Principe",
      "name_es": " Santo Tomé y Príncipe",
      "dial_code": "+239",
      "code": "ST"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Saudi Arabia",
      "name_es": "Arabia Saudita",
      "dial_code": "+966",
      "code": "SA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Senegal",
      "name_es": "Senegal",
      "dial_code": "+221",
      "code": "SN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Serbia",
      "name_es": "Serbia",
      "dial_code": "+381",
      "code": "RS"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Seychelles",
      "name_es": "Seychelles",
      "dial_code": "+248",
      "code": "SC"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Sierra Leone",
      "name_es": "Sierra Leona",
      "dial_code": "+232",
      "code": "SL"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Singapore",
      "name_es": "Singapur",
      "dial_code": "+65",
      "code": "SG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Slovakia",
      "name_es": "Eslovaquia",
      "dial_code": "+421",
      "code": "SK"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Slovenia",
      "name_es": "Eslovenia",
      "dial_code": "+386",
      "code": "SI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Solomon Islands",
      "name_es": "Islas Salomón",
      "dial_code": "+677",
      "code": "SB"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Somalia",
      "name_es": "Somalia",
      "dial_code": "+252",
      "code": "SO"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "South Africa",
      "name_es": "Sudáfrica",
      "dial_code": "+27",
      "code": "ZA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "South Sudan",
      "name_es": "Sudán del Sur",
      "dial_code": "+211",
      "code": "SS"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Spain",
      "name_es": "España",
      "dial_code": "+34",
      "code": "ES"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Sri Lanka",
      "name_es": "Sri Lanka",
      "dial_code": "+94",
      "code": "LK"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "State of Palestine",
      "name_es": "Estado de Palestina",
      "dial_code": "+970",
      "code": "PS"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Sudan",
      "name_es": "Sudán",
      "dial_code": "+249",
      "code": "SD"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Suriname",
      "name_es": "Surinam",
      "dial_code": "+597",
      "code": "SR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
      "name_es": "Svalbard y Jan Mayen",
      "dial_code": "+47",
      "code": "SJ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Swaziland",
      "name_es": "Suazilandia",
      "dial_code": "+268",
      "code": "SZ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Sweden",
      "name_es": "Suecia",
      "dial_code": "+46",
      "code": "SE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Switzerland",
      "name_es": "Suiza",
      "dial_code": "+41",
      "code": "CH"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Syrian Arab Republic",
      "name_es": "Siria",
      "dial_code": "+963",
      "code": "SY"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Taiwan, Province of China",
      "name_es": "Taiwán",
      "dial_code": "+886",
      "code": "TW"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Tayikistan",
      "name_es": "Tayikistán",
      "dial_code": "+992",
      "code": "TJ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Trinidad and Tobago",
      "name_es": "Trinidad y Tobago",
      "dial_code": "+1868",
      "code": "TT"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Tunisia",
      "name_es": "Túnez",
      "dial_code": "+216",
      "code": "TN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Turkey",
      "name_es": "Turquía",
      "dial_code": "+90",
      "code": "TR"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Turkmenistan",
      "name_es": "Turkmenistán",
      "dial_code": "+993",
      "code": "TM"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Ukraine",
      "name_es": "Ucrania",
      "dial_code": "+380",
      "code": "UA"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "United Arab Emirates",
      "name_es": "Emiratos Árabes Unidos",
      "dial_code": "+971",
      "code": "AE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "United Kingdom",
      "name_es": "Reino Unido",
      "dial_code": "+44",
      "code": "GB"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "United States",
      "name_es": "Estados Unidos",
      "dial_code": "+1",
      "code": "US"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Uruguay",
      "name_es": "Uruguay",
      "dial_code": "+598",
      "code": "UY"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Uzbekistan",
      "name_es": "Uzbekistán",
      "dial_code": "+998",
      "code": "UZ"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",
      "name_es": "Venezuela",
      "dial_code": "+58",
      "code": "VE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Vietnam",
      "name_es": "Vietnam",
      "dial_code": "+84",
      "code": "VN"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Virgin Islands, British",
      "name_es": "Islas Vírgenes Británicas",
      "dial_code": "+1284",
      "code": "VG"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Virgin Islands, U.S.",
      "name_es": "Islas Vírgenes de los Estados Unidos",
      "dial_code": "+1340",
      "code": "VI"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Wallis and Futuna",
      "name_es": "Wallis y Futuna",
      "dial_code": "+681",
      "code": "WF"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Yemen",
      "name_es": "Yemen",
      "dial_code": "+967",
      "code": "YE"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Åland Islands",
      "name_es": "Åland",
      "dial_code": "+358",
      "code": "AX"
    }
  ]
}
```

My class view looks like such

```
class SubmitView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        context = {}
        form = AddDefenitionForm()
        context['countries'] = COUNTRIES
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, "submit.html", context)
```

And my submit.html looks like such

```
{% for p in countries.countries|dictsort:"name_es" %}
<option value="{{ p.code|lower }}">{{ p.name_es }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

For some reason it, México shows up at the end of the M in that dictionary.

Comment: @Jarad python 3.8.10 and django-3.2.8 and from my experience, yes, can be seen live here https://diccionarioespañol.com/definir-una-palabra/ how it orders the countries where it says `pais de inicio`

Comment: It's because of the accent of the letter `é`. Replace it with a normal `e` and it should work.

Comment: @EnePaul that doesn't solve the issue though, as there are other country names with accents.  As well as alphabet letters, such as ñ in other dictionaries as well..

Comment: Then remove all accents.

Comment: Or create another field for each country. Something like "name_es_noaccent" which you can order by.

Answer (score 0):

Per Ene Paul's comment, you might want to add a `name_normalized` key/value to your dictionary.

I can't post the full dictionary solution, but you can do this yourself simply with a [strip_accents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/518232/1577947) function.

```
for d in COUNTRIES['countries']:
    d['name_normalized'] = strip_accents(d['name_es'])
```

Then use a Python online formatter for the output (optional). Paste over your existing countries list.

Then in template:

```
<select name="countries" id="countries">
  {% for p in countries.countries|dictsort:"name_normalized" %}
    <option value="{{ p.code|lower }}">{{ p.name_es }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

(also, remove extra empty space in front of " Santo Tomé y Príncipe")

[image]